# Why do you want this job?

Tags: professionalism

Most of the time I face an interview. A common question is there **Why do you want this job.**

Should I be telling them that **I don't have a choice as there are no other job options** or something else.

Comment: We generally try to avoid directly feeding people specific things to say, so this is likely to be closed, but in the spirit of being helpful, do not say "I have no other options."

Comment: This may be more helpful: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/how-to-respond-to-why-are-you-looking-for-a-new-job

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing...  There's a bit of a conundrum here.

Lying is unseemly, certainly.  On the other hand, I as a hiring manager would take a really dim view on an answer such as "I don't have a choice as there are no other job options".  It gives the impression that my company is your *very last choice*, and makes me want to hire someone else.

So, what to do?

Recommendation:

**Make the best of it.**  Do some research on the company and the position.  Surely there's *something* positive you can say about them.  Find it, and focus on that.  Maybe you like their product.  Maybe you like their corporate culture (they always brag about it on their website).  In short, find something nice worth saying!

**TL;DR --  research until you do find something good you can honestly say about joining the company**

Comment: Thanks a lot@akaioi

Comment: Lying is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @MisterPositive agreed; the basic thrust of my advice is to research until you do find something good you can honestly say